# Force <div> to fill all available vertical space

Tags: html, css

I've seen a pile of ways to do this online, but all that I've tried either break other CSS on the page or don't work all together.

On this page http://www.psyklopz.com/workbench/ I would like to get the #container element to grow in height so that the footer touches the bottom of the screen.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `position: fixed;` and setting `bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0;`.  I then used a piece of jQuery `.animate()` magic to pull it off.  Here's the working code and a demo all-in-one!
http://www.psyklopz.com/workbench/jquery-based-dock-toolbar/

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

i visited the sight. Well if your content is just as short as that and you want to still put the footer touch the bottom of the screen. add this to your css of the div or container that you want to be at the bottom.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! The left:0, right:0 is what I needed.  It would fall to the left corner without it!

Comment: Oh no! This causes the footer to cover up content on pages where the #contain element is taller than the page.

Comment: I didn't use what you gave me, but you got me much closer to the answer, so I owe you a big thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Styles

```
html,body {height: 100%;}
body{ position: relative;}
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

The container div won't stretch the whole way down, but with clever use of BG colors you can make it look like it does.

Comment: I found that nothing worked for me until I set the html height to 100%. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @user1208434 that is working for me +1.  - Do you recall where you found that setting? URL?

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%;` to both the `#page` and `#contain`  divs. That will get you what you want.

Comment: Nope, tried that.  It screws up other pages layouts.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi see the live demo:-

http://jsfiddle.net/BER5x/2/

you can use this code its fixed at bottom and without your footer top curve image its totally css border radius property you don't need to use the footer-top in your css.

I hope this will help you......

Comment: Great idea, I definitely appreciate the help.  Check out my solution in another answer, the border-radius does a lot!

Comment: thanks you can make your footer totally css based you don't need any image for that if you will use border-radius and background-color in your footer.....

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but I found myself with a similar problem today.

I wanted to have a container (with a map) to fill the viewport, but there had to be a 32px high container above it. The map made it necessary, to really extend the container to its maximum possible size and to not overlap with anything else.
I ended up using a flexible and elegant solution without any javascript:

```
<div class="tab"><div class="tabContent" /></div
<div class="container" />
```

And the CSS:

```
.tab {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabContent {
  height: 32px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The trick is using box-sizing: border-box to make the height: 100% include the defined padding.

I have also created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWLLM/2/
I had to use a fixed body height in the fiddle, because (at least in chrome) in the iframe body height: 100% didn't work.
I also added some borders to visualize, that nothing get's cut off (with container overflow: hidden)